# Getting a NSViewController's View if it is a custom class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller

I use the following code to get my View out of my controller:

```
CollectionItemView *myView = [self view];
```

This works pretty well, but I get the warning `Incompatible pointer types initializing CollectionItemView __strong with an expression of type NSView`. I understand why i get this but is it okay to ignore it or should I overwrite the view property ?

chuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that `[self view]` is `CollectionItemView` just do:

```
CollectionItemView *myView = (CollectionItemView*)[self view];
```

or (which is better) you can use:

```
id myView = [self view];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to overwrite it. troolee already suggested two working solutions. 
However, just to be save I'd rather code it differently.

```
CollectionItemView *myView = nil;
if ([[self view] isKindOfClass:[CollectionItemView class])
  self.view = (CollectionItemView*)[self view];
```

The shorter version without isKindOfClass test is ok when you know for sure from the context that the object must be of type CollectionItemView or any of its subclasses.